# Remove string first and last letter if matches found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some scenario to remove the first and last letter of a string if given string matches. Give string is `$` in this scenario.

Example:

```
    $test 1 sql server$
    $ $test 2 sql server
    test 3 sql server$ $
    $test 4 sql server
    test 5 sql server
    $test 6 sql server
```

Remove if the first and last character contains `$` in a string. And remove two `$ $` with spaces, in the second row beginning and third row end also.

Required result

```
test 1 sql server
test 2 sql server
test 3 sql server
test 4 sql server
test 5 sql server
test 6 sql server
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Tried the `REPLACE` function? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: Are you use $ inside word? (same as **'$test 3 sql ser$ver'** -> result-> test 3 sql ser$ver)

Answer (score 1):

First replace '$ $' with '', then replace '$' with ''.
You where saying: replace with spaces, but in your results are no spaces so I replaced them with empty strings. You can modify it to your needs of course.
So this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(YourColumn, '$ $', ''),'$','')
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Value VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('$test 1 sql server$'),
('$ $test 2 sql server'),
('$test 3 sql server$ '),
('$test 4 sql server'),
('test 5 sql server'),
('$test 6 sql server')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Value, '$', ''))) AS Fixed
FROM @TABLE
WHERE LEFT(LTRIM(Value), 1) = '$'
OR RIGHT(LTRIM(Value), 1) = '$'
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════════════╗
║       Fixed        ║
╠════════════════════╣
║ test 1 sql server  ║
║ test 2 sql server  ║
║ test 3 sql server  ║
║ test 4 sql server  ║
║ test 6 sql server  ║
╚════════════════════╝
```

Comment: You might want to stick an RTRIM on the select clause depending on the data.

Comment: it doesnt really make much differece though anyway I have done it :)

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you i don't want replcae if $ found in between the string. i want to remove from begning and end $ only. sorry i din't mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stuff function
Replace $ with ''

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT REPLACE('$test 1 sql server$','$','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace $ with '' but in this example that not work:

```
 test 3 sql ser$ver$ $
```

But this algorithm work fine:

```
DECLARE @in NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @out NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @in=' test 3 sql server$ $'
SET @out=''


DECLARE @separator NCHAR(1)
SET @separator=' '
DECLARE @position int
SET @position = 1
SET @in = @in + @separator

WHILE charindex(@separator,@in,@position) <> 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @word NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @word = substring(@in, @position, charindex(@separator,@in,@position) - @position)

        IF (LEN(@Word)=1 AND @Word='$') SET @Word=''
        ELSE
        BEGIN
          IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,1,1)='$') SET @Word=SUBSTRING(@Word,2,LEN(@word))
          IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,LEN(@word),1)='$') SET @Word=SUBSTRING(@Word,1,LEN(@word)-1)
        END

        SET @out=@out+@separator+@word
        SET @position = charindex(@separator,@in,@position) + 1
    END


SELECT @out
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using this method a lot, in a few different places, then create a scalar function, and do a simple replace:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.StripTokens', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.StripTokens;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripTokens (@string VARCHAR(MAX), @token CHAR(1))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @outputString = REPLACE(@string, @token, '')
    SET @outputString = REPLACE(@outputString, '  ', ' ')
    SET @outputString = RTRIM(LTRIM(@outputString))
    RETURN(@outputString);
END;
```

And in use:

```
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test 1 sql server$', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$ $test 2 sql server', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('test 3 sql server$ $', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test 4 sql server', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('test 5 sql server', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test 6 sql server', '$')
```

Which produces:

```
test 1 sql server
test 2 sql server
test 3 sql server
test 4 sql server
test 5 sql server
test 6 sql server
```

This will also work for '$test $7 sql server$', but will not replace more than 2 multiple spaces:

```
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test $7 sql server$', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test    $ $8 sql server', '$')
```

Results:

```
test 7 sql server
test   8 sql server
```

To replace multiple spaces, you would need to create a loop that uses PATINDEX to check if there are any remaining double spaces. Here's the same function with this functionality available:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.StripTokens', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.StripTokens;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripTokens (@string VARCHAR(MAX), @token CHAR(1))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @outputString = REPLACE(@string, @token, '')

    WHILE(1 = 1)
        BEGIN
            IF PATINDEX('%  %', @outputString) > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @outputString = REPLACE(@outputString, '  ', ' ')
                END
            ELSE
                BREAK
        END

    SET @outputString = RTRIM(LTRIM(@outputString))
    RETURN(@outputString);
END;

GO

PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test 1 sql server$', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$ $test 2 sql server', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('test 3 sql server$ $', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test 4 sql server', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('test 5 sql server', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test 6 sql server', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test $7 sql server$', '$')
PRINT dbo.StripTokens('$test    $ $8 sql server', '$')
```

Returns:

```
test 1 sql server
test 2 sql server
test 3 sql server
test 4 sql server
test 5 sql server
test 6 sql server
test 7 sql server
test 8 sql server
```

This is the closest you get to regular expressions in T-SQl without using the CLR or interop.

Comment: If you are trying to replace placeholders in a string, then you should use some form of regular expression or pattern checking to validate each placeholder.

Comment: Hi Spikeh Thank You, I am not sure allways first and last charater will be $ in my scenario.

Comment: I modified the post a while back, but didn't see your comment until now. This code will remove any $ signs from the string, and remove any leading or trailing spaces from it. You could also apply a second REPLACE() function to remove any double whitespaces left over after the replacement, but it would only work for the first iteration; you would need to loop the replacement until all double whitespaces are removed.

Comment: @RajeshGK I've updated my answer to include a comprehensive example.